# What CSS is responsible for center aligning the div 'columns twelve' in this page

Tags: html, css

If we look at the the page http://www.groupon.co.uk/deals/edinburgh/white-apple-2-6/55361548 there is a div element with CSS classes `columns` and `twelve`. It seems to me that this class is somehow responsible for a center aligned container - which has an equally spaced margin on the left and right.

[image]

I have tried studying the CSS on this page for quite some time to determine what piece of CSS is responsible for the center placing of the main content of the page but I cannot find what is giving this div the placement in the center.

Can somebody please highlight for me the CSS assigned to columns twelve class on this page giving the center with white spacing on the left and right of the div? Thank you!

Comment: HTML/CSS classes can't have spaces in their names; spaces are used in HTML to assign multiple classes. Just going by your description, the HTML is assigning the elements two classes: one named `columns`, and another named `twelve`.

Comment: I meant classes rather than class - sorry - I have altered the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit doing the centering is the `.row` container:

```
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns twelve">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
...
```

The CSS for `.row` that is centering its content (the `.columns twelve` div) is :

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
```

By giving `.row` a defined `width`, and setting the left and right `margin` to auto, the browser will automatically center it. The content div `.columns twelve` is then set to 100% `width` (more specifically the `twelve` class is setting the `width` to 100%) makes the content expand to fill the 960px of the `.row`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the parent div with clas "row". It has a width and 'margin 0 auto' that's aligning the div in the center.

```
.row {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.columns.twelve` **is not centered**. It's left-floating. The only reason it appears centered is because its' parent has both left and right margins set to `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

actually `.columns twelve` is assigning a width 100% to the div,

then it's parent is `row` with `margin: 0 auto;` that's centering the div

inside `section main` container ,